# localhost not connecting to server after upgrade to php7

Tags: php, php-7, macos-sierra

PHP 5.6 was working fine in my Mac Sierra I tried to upgrade to 7.0 than it stopped working. when I try to run localhost safari it shows not connected to server error.

Comment: Have you started the server?

Comment: Yes. It was perfectly working it stopped after upgrade.

Comment: are you still using mysql lib?

Comment: No. I am trying to test with simple file which just has phpinfo();

Comment: If it stopped after upgrading, have you restarted it? Is there any message logged to the server's error log, eg. at `/var/log/apache` or a folder like that?

Comment: No its upgraded. even when I type php -v I am getting newer version. and there is no apache error too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder: `/usr/local/opt/` Delete `php70` folder.

Then run: `brew install php70` or brew `install php70 --with-httpd24`

Then try to run the localhost again.

**Or** you may try to update php 5 to php 7 again on Sierra.These are the steps-Usually, with a fresh version of macOS Sierra, you get a PHP 5.6 installed.

You’ve got two options: `brew or curl install`

**Brew**

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew unlink php56 
brew install php70
```

You might get an error if PHP 5.6 has not been installed by brew previously, but don't worry, you can simply continue
**CURL**

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0
```

You can replace 7.0 by 7.1 in the command above to get version 7.1 of PHP.

Reference - [Medium](https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-upgrade-your-version-of-php-to-7-0-on-macos-sierra-e1bfdea55a63)

Comment: opt folder not found

Comment: is there any file php70 in your   /usr/local . then delete it and follow the steps. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel   38 Mar 21 21:25 php5 -> /usr/local/php5-7.0.27-20180201-135220
drwxr-xr-x  15 root      wheel  510 Mar 21 21:49 php5-7.0.27-20180201-135220

found only this two related to php.

Comment: I found it just had to comment LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so line in http.conf and It started working.

Comment: great.. :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found it just had to comment LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so line in http.conf and It started working. since it wad trying to find both version and not working.